# Optimizing save time when using Python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, png, jpeg

I´m using PIL (with Python 3 on a Raspberry) to read a background file (PNG, 1920x1080), add a few text elements to it, and then save it as another file with the same format.

The process is somewhat time critical, and the sooner the new file is saved to the Raspberry´s SD card, the better.

The code is quite basic:

```
img = Image.open('background.png')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((100, 100, 'test',myColor,myFont)
img.save('newfile.png')
```

I´ve timed the process and it takes a good 3 to 4 secs to execute the last line and save the file.

Is there any way to optimize the speed of this, without sacrificing quality (resolution, colors, etc)?

Now I´m about to test JPG instead of PNG.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

The original timing was running Python 3 interpreter. After compiling my script (*pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py*), the saving time goes down to 2.2 secs.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is useful to someone in the future: switching image file format from PNG to JPG reduced the time to save the FullHD file (1920 x 1080 px) to less than 1 second!